# Continuously capture packets in Pyshark

Tags: python-3.x, sniffing, pyshark

This [tutorial](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/using-pyshark-in-python-to-create-promiscuous-sniffer-ddb5217f3d5) and this [documentation](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark) describes how to capture packets in a live interface. 
However, you have to specify a limit (either the number of packets or a timeout) in order to start sniffing:

```
capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='eth0')
capture.sniff(timeout=50)
```

OR

```
cap.sniff(packet_count=50)
```

**My question**: Is there a way to keep on capturing packets without specifying a limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can continuously sniff packets using sniff_continuously().  Below is some sample code for continuously processing TCP packets from a network interface.

```
def capture_live_packets(network_interface):
    capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=network_interface)
    for raw_packet in capture.sniff_continuously():
        print(filter_all_tcp_traffic_file(raw_packet))

def get_packet_details(packet):
    """
    This function is designed to parse specific details from an individual packet.
    :param packet: raw packet from either a pcap file or via live capture using TShark
    :return: specific packet details
    """
    protocol = packet.transport_layer
    source_address = packet.ip.src
    source_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].srcport
    destination_address = packet.ip.dst
    destination_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].dstport
    packet_time = packet.sniff_time
    return f'Packet Timestamp: {packet_time}' \
           f'\nProtocol type: {protocol}' \
           f'\nSource address: {source_address}' \
           f'\nSource port: {source_port}' \
           f'\nDestination address: {destination_address}' \
           f'\nDestination port: {destination_port}\n'


def filter_all_tcp_traffic_file(packet):
    """
    This function is designed to parse all the Transmission Control Protocol(TCP) packets
    :param packet: raw packet
    :return: specific packet details
    """
    if hasattr(packet, 'tcp'):
       results = get_packet_details(packet)
       return results

capture_live_packets('en0')
```